# malloc error using Boost with OSX

Tags: c++, macos, boost, malloc, iostream

I'm trying to use the Boost iostream library in OSX with gcc 4.7 (since I'll be using C++11 features).  The following code compiles and links, but fails at runtime:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  std::string fname(argv[1]);

  std::ifstream file(fname.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
  try {
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
    in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(boost::iostreams::file_source(fname));
    for( std::string str; std::getline(in, str); ) {
      std::cout << "Processed line " << str << '\n';
    }
   }
   catch(const boost::iostreams::gzip_error& e) {
   std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
  }
}
```

With the following error:

```
MapProbesToGenes(70632) malloc: *** error for object 0x100168860: pointer being freed    was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Running this under GDB, the stackframe is the following

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007fff8b0d0d46 in __kill ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8b0d0d46 in __kill ()
#1  0x00007fff88f52e1c in abort ()
#2  0x00007fff88f26989 in free ()
#3  0x00007fff84365e7c in std::string::reserve ()
#4  0x00007fff8436606e in std::string::push_back ()
#5  0x00007fff8436602d in std::string::operator+= ()
#6  0x000000010006f307 in boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_header::process (this=0x113e8, c=6 '\006') at gzip.cpp:100
#7  0x000000010000f435 in boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > ()
#8  0x000000010000f13e in boost::iostreams::detail::read_filter_impl<boost::iostreams::multichar_tag>::read<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >, boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > ()
#9  0x000000010000edd7 in boost::iostreams::read<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >, boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > ()
#10 0x000000010000e557 in boost::iostreams::detail::flt_wrapper_impl<boost::iostreams::input>::read<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >, boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > ()
#11 0x000000010000e1d8 in boost::iostreams::detail::concept_adapter<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> > >::read<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > ()
#12 0x000000010000d020 in boost::iostreams::detail::indirect_streambuf<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, boost::iostreams::input>::underflow ()
#13 0x00000001000be63a in std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > ()
```

I've done a good bit of searching online, but I can't find a satisfactory solution that resolves this issue.

Comment: Was the version of boost you are using built with gcc 4.7? If it wasn't, then that is probably the problem. Try building boost with gcc 4.7.

Comment: It feels like you're corrupting your heap somehow... but I can't put my finger on how.  Can you try flushing cout inside the for loop to see how many iterations you're getting?  By the way, the first loop through will always read an empty line - not sure if that's intentional.

Comment: Well it looks to be somewhat of a mess.  I find random references to a similar problem (the malloc error) in many places.  When I try to compile boost with gcc47, a number of libraries fail to build.  It seems to be related to this issue (http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53838).  What a headache!  I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: P.S.  I just checked that this exact code correctly compiles and runs using the same versions of boost and gcc on linux.